# Custom signals and multi-parameter slots

Tags: python, variables, pyqt5, signals-slots

I am using PyQt5 for my project. I have a widget class which returns a custom signal based on some other signal. This signal will connect to a slot, which will use the signal information to do something based on some other parameters. The problem is that I do not know how to include both, the parameters that the signal itself passes, and the ones that I want to include in the slot. Here a toy model (I know it does not make practical sense, but it still shows my case):

```
class Buttons(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    pressed_button = qtc.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
         self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()

         self.button1.setObjectName('button1')
         self.button2.setObjectName('button2')

         self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pressed_button)
         self.button2.clicked.connect(self.pressed_button)

    def pressed_button(self):
        
        if self.sender().objectName() == 'button1':
           self.pressed_button.emit(1)
        elif self.sender().objectName() == 'button2':
           self.pressed_button.emit(2)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         self.buttons = Buttons()

         self.buttons.pressed_button.connect(self.print_button('Pressed button is '))

    def print_button(self, n, msg):

         print(msg + str(n))
```

The issue is that if you give the msg = 'Pressed button is ', the pring button function still expects you give variable 'n', when what I want is that this variable comes directly from the emitted signal. How can I solve this?

Comment: The connection in `MainWindow` is wrong, as you're calling the function (and connections expect the reference to the function). In any case, try with `self.buttons.pressed_button.connect(lambda n: self.print_button(n, 'Pressed button is '))`.

Comment: Use a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) and connect to its [idClicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#idClicked).

Comment: The solution of musicamante is exactly what I needed. Thanks!